# Ошибка при вызове функции: ORA-29540: class <name> does not exist

Tags: java, oracle, oracle18c

Создаю класс:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED getipbyhost AS
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
        
public class myipbyhost {
    public static void main(String a[]){
        try {
            InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName("myhost.domain");
            System.out.println(host.getHostAddress());
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
/
```

И функцию для вызова:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION gethost RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
LANGUAGE JAVA
        NAME 'getipbyhost.myipbyhost() return java.lang.string';
/
```

Пытаюсь получить разультат, но выводит ошибку:

```
select gethost() from dual
/
```

> [Error] Execution (1: 23): ORA-29540: class getipbyhost does not exist

В чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getipbyhost` это не класс, а имя исходного кода (`JAVA SOURCE`), с которым он хранится в БД.
И далее, что должна вернуть функция `gethost`, если `main` ничего не возвращает.

Попробуйте так:

```
create or replace and compile java source named getipbyhost AS
    import java.net.InetAddress;
    import java.net.UnknownHostException;
        
    public class MyIpByHost {
    public static void main(String a[]) {
        try {
            InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName(a[1]);
            System.out.println(a[0]+": "+host.getHostAddress());
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
/
create or replace procedure printhost(msg varchar2, host varchar2) as
    language java name 'MyIpByHost.main(java.lang.String[])';
/
```

Получить результат:

```
set serveroutput on
exec dbms_java.set_output(10000)

exec printhost ('host ip','localhost')
```

> host ip: 127.0.0.1

Comment: спасибо! то что нужно :)